# controlling the date format in a sent email from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using this code below to send the email my question is using the date dropdown box how can I control how the date is displayed in the email received? Right now its being displayed **yy/mm/dd** I'm trying to set it up for **mm/dd/yy**

```
protected void Send_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress("");
        msg.To.Add("");
        msg.Subject = "Email";
        msg.Body = string.Format("First Name: <b>{0}</b><br/>Last Name: <b>{1}</b><br/>Email: <b>{2}</b><br/>Certificate number: <b>{3}</b><br/>Preferred itinerary: <b>{4}</b><br/>Preferred departure date: <b>{5}</b><br/>Number of travelers: <b>{6}</b><br/>Number of cabins: <b>{7}</b><br/>Cabin type: <b>{8}</b>", this.FirstName_TextBox.Text, this.LastName_TextBox.Text, this.Email_TextBox.Text, this.CertificateNumber_TextBox.Text, this.PreferredItinerary_DropDownList.Text, this.PreferredDepartureDate_TextBox.Text, this.NumberOfTravelers_TextBox.Text, this.NumberOfCabins_TextBox.Text, this.CabinType_DropDownList.Text);
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        SmtpClient smt = new SmtpClient("smtpout.secureserver.net", 80);
        smt.EnableSsl = false;
        smt.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
        smt.Send(msg);
        this.Response.Redirect("ThankYou.aspx");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.ResultLabel.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, turn the value into an actual `DateTime`.  Something as simple this perhaps:

```
DateTime departureDate;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(this.PreferredDepartureDate_TextBox.Text, out departureDate))
    // couldn't parse the date, show an error
```

(You may need to use a [custom format provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx) depending on the originating format and current culture.)

Once you have a valid `DateTime` object, you can [represent it as a string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) any way you like.  For example:

```
departureDate.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy")
```

Comment: So quick! :) Just a suggestion,knowing that origin date is in yy/mm/dd format you could use TryParseExact